# Perform an operation within grouped pairs in tidyverse

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

I have a dataset with three columns that are grouped by two variables.

```
df <- tibble(paper = rep(c("A_2012", "B_2019"), each = 5), 
       question = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 2), 
       rate = c(4.545455, 4.010000, 4.672727, 4.100000, 3.418182, 3.060000,
         4.563636, 3.760000, 4.636364, 4.000000))

> df %>% group_by(question) %>% 
select(question, paper, rate) %>% 
arrange(question)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   question [5]
  question    paper   rate
   <dbl>     <.chr>  <dbl>
 1  1        A_2012   4.55
 2  1        B_2019   3.06
 3  2        A_2012   4.01
 4  2        B_2019   4.56
 5  3        A_2012   4.67
 6  3        B_2019   3.76
 7  4        A_2012   4.1 
 8  4        B_2019   4.64
 9  5        A_2012   3.42
10  5        B_2019   4
```

I need to perform an operation within the 'rate' values of a group. But really, I do not know how to write the code using `tidyverse` style. In this example, I´ll get the difference (paperB - paperA) for each question:

```
    > df_result
    # A tibble: 5 x 2
     question diff_rate
       <dbl>     <dbl>
1        1     -1.49
2        2      0.55
3        3     -0.91
4        4      0.54
5        5      0.58
```

I´ve tried using `pivot_wider`and then some operations but I have actually 54 different values for the variable paper, so it is not efficient.
Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
df %>% group_by(question) %>% 
  select(question, paper, rate) %>% 
  arrange(question) %>% mutate(
    diff_rate=diff(rate)
```

if you wanna the same format as your df_result, you can do

```
df %>% group_by(question) %>% 
  select(question, paper, rate) %>% 
  arrange(question) %>% mutate(
    diff_rate=diff(rate)
  ) %>% select(question, diff_rate) %>% distinct()
```